# Why are my parses and for loops not working in java?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, user-interface, swt

I'm working on a program to demonstrate arrays in GUI, but I've hit a few snags. I can't get the parsing right and I have two for loops that seem to be having trouble with their i variable. As I'm not sure where the snag is, exactly, I included the entire program; there's not a lot of it, it's a pretty small application.

The parsing issues are on lines 83 and 84; the two for loops are on lines 90-97.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;


public class Monthly_Budget_Calculator {

    protected Shell shell;
    private Text txtIntegerDynamic;
    private Text txtStringDynamic;

    private int maxSize = 20;
    private String[] stackArrayString = new String[maxSize];
    private int[] stackArrayInt = new int[maxSize];
    private int top = -1;

    public void intpush(int i) {
        stackArrayInt[++top] = i;
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Monthly_Budget_Calculator window = new Monthly_Budget_Calculator();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */

    protected void createContents() {

        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 750);
        shell.setText("Monthly Budget Calculator");

        Label lblStringStatic = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblStringStatic.setBounds(10, 98, 145, 15);
        lblStringStatic.setText("Enter a string value here:");

        txtStringDynamic = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        txtStringDynamic.setBounds(10, 119, 182, 21);

        Label lblIntegerStatic = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblIntegerStatic.setBounds(198, 98, 145, 15);
        lblIntegerStatic.setText("Enter a decimal value here:");

        txtIntegerDynamic = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        txtIntegerDynamic.setBounds(198, 119, 145, 21);

        Button btnAdd = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnAdd.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // adds values to arrays
                // I'M TRYING TO PARSE THESE TEXT FIELDS INTO THE ARRAY, I JUST HAVEN"T BEEN ABLE TO GET THESE TWO LINES WORKING
                stackArrayInt.push(Integer.parseInt(txtIntegerDynamic.getText()));
                stackArrayString.push(txtStringDynamic.getText()));
                // clears fields
                txtStringDynamic.setText("");
                txtIntegerDynamic.setText("");
                // prints to fields
                String valueToBeInserted="";
                // THESE FOR LOOPS ARE HAVING TROUBLE WITH THE I VARIABLE, NOT SURE WHY
                for (i = 0; i<stackArrayString.length; i++)
                {
                    valueToBeInserted = valueToBeInserted + "\r\n" + stackArrayString[i];
                }
                for (i = 0; i<stackArrayInt.length; i++)
                {
                    valueToBeInserted = valueToBeInserted + "\r\n" + stackArrayInt[i];
                }
            }
        });
        btnAdd.setBounds(349, 117, 75, 25);
        btnAdd.setText("Add");

        Label lblExplanation = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblExplanation.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        lblExplanation.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 82);
        lblExplanation.setText("This calculator is for budgeting monthly expenses. \r\nAdd the string value descriptor of the expense on the left. \r\nAdd the decimal value descriptor of the expense on the right.\r\nClick \"Add\" to add the expense to the list.\r\nClick \"Clear\" to clear all expenses from the list and start over.");

        Label lblListStatic = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblListStatic.setBounds(110, 161, 210, 15);
        lblListStatic.setText("The current expenses accounted for are:");

        final Label lblListString = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        lblListString.setBounds(60, 182, 203, 450);

        final Label lblListInteger = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        lblListInteger.setBounds(265, 182, 104, 450);

        Label lblBudgetStatic = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblBudgetStatic.setBounds(20, 654, 182, 15);
        lblBudgetStatic.setText("Your monthly budget thus far is:");

        Label lblBudgetDynamic = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblBudgetDynamic.setBounds(30, 675, 104, 15);

        Button btnClear = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnClear.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // empties arrays
                stackArrayInt = null;
                stackArrayInt = null;
                // empties fields and labels
                txtStringDynamic.setText("");
                txtIntegerDynamic.setText("");
                lblListString.setText(""); // made field final
                lblListInteger.setText(""); // made field final

            }
        });
        btnClear.setBounds(289, 665, 75, 25);
        btnClear.setText("Clear");

        Label divOne = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        divOne.setBounds(110, 90, 210, 2);

        Label divTwo = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        divTwo.setBounds(110, 153, 210, 2);

        Label divThree = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        divThree.setBounds(110, 646, 210, 2);

    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:swing] tag removed, [tag:swt] tag added. Your question has nothing to do with Swing and by mistagging your question, you're attracting the wrong experts to it.

Comment: You may not know where the problem is in the code, but you should describe what you are observing and how that is different from what you are expecting. Otherwise nobody can help.

Comment: In this case it looks like you get a *compiler error* as opposed to things in the GUI not showing like you expect. Just add `int i;` on a separate line before the first for-loop. In Java you need to declare a variable and its type before you can use it.

Comment: Right on, thanks, that takes care of the for loops. Still struggling with parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `int i;` on a separate line before the first for-loop.

In Java you need to declare a variable and its type before you can use it.

```
            int i; // <---- HERE
            for (i = 0; i<stackArrayString.length; i++)
            {
                valueToBeInserted = valueToBeInserted + "\r\n" + stackArrayString[i];
            }
            for (i = 0; i<stackArrayInt.length; i++)
            {
                valueToBeInserted = valueToBeInserted + "\r\n" + stackArrayInt[i];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `i` first:

```
for (int i = 0; i<stackArrayString.length; i++)
{
    valueToBeInserted = valueToBeInserted + "\r\n" + stackArrayString[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i<stackArrayInt.length; i++)
{
    valueToBeInserted = valueToBeInserted + "\r\n" + stackArrayInt[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your parsers is that simple arrays in java don't have a push method like the ones you are trying to call. If you need the push/pop functionality of a Stack data structure you'd better go for a Deque like this:

```
    Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    Deque<String> stack2 = new ArrayDeque<String>();
    //...
    stack.push(123);
    stack.push("abc");
```

The problem with your `i` variable is simply that it hasn't been declared anywhere in your code, as already stated in the other answers.